# How to extract multiple values from a string to call an array?

Tags: php, regex

I want to extract values from a string to call an array for basic template functionality:

```
$string = '... #these.are.words-I_want.to.extract# ...';

$output = preg_replace_callback('~\#([\w-]+)(\.([\w-]+))*\#~', function($matches) {
    print_r($matches);
    // Replace matches with array value: $these['are']['words-I_want']['to']['extract']
}, $string);
```

This gives me:

```
Array
(
    [0] => #these.are.words-I_want.to.extract#
    [1] => these
    [2] => .extract
    [3] => extract
)
```

But I'd like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => #these.are.words-I_want.to.extract#
    [1] => these
    [2] => are
    [3] => words-I_want
    [4] => to
    [5] => extract
)
```

Which changes do I need to make to my regex?

Comment: Seems like an `explode('.', $yourvar)` is what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the words are simply dot separated, so match sequences of what you don't want:

```
preg_replace_callback('/[^#.]+/', function($match) {
    // ...
}, $str);
```

Should give the expected results.

However, if the `#` characters are the boundary of where the matching should take place, you would need a separate match and then use a simple `explode()` inside:

```
preg_replace_callback('/#(.*?)#/', function($match) {
    $parts = explode('.', $match[1]);
    // ...
}, $str);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`array_merge()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) function to merge the two resulting arrays:

```
$string = '... #these.are.words-I_want.to.extract# ...';
$result = array();

if (preg_match('~#([^#]+)#~', $string, $m)) {
   $result[] = $m[0];
   $result = array_merge($result, explode('.', $m[1]));
}

print_r($result);
```

###Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => #these.are.words-I_want.to.extract#
    [1] => these
    [2] => are
    [3] => words-I_want
    [4] => to
    [5] => extract
)
```

Comment: Hey there anu, nearly identical answer, deleting mine and +1 to you :) Off to sleep catch you tomorrow.

Comment: Sorry just came back online, missed identical answer part otherwise I would have avoided answering it.

Comment: No, you're absolutely fine, my original answer didn't have the demo, and when you started on your answer I must have been in IDEONE trying to make mine work. We probably got there around the same time, and you got there in a shorter amount of time, so kudos to you. :) After I posted, I saw that yours was similar and had a small bug but you fixed it. My answer doesn't add anything, hope yours gets some upvotes. Sorry, too chatty, powering down the computer see you tomorrow.:)